# onlayout not be called

Tags: java, android, layout, view, touch-event

Here is my code to set my 3*2 layout, and when I initialize the view in the onCreateView() method, and use setX(100) with the second following code, everything works as I thought, i.e. the whole 3*2 view move right for 100 pixel. When I add touch event listener, and change the view position with setX(100) there, then the onlayout() is not called, it is just like a 3*1 layout.

So how to call this onLayout when I received a touch event?

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    int mTotalHeight = 0;  
    int mTotalWidth = 0;
    int childCount = getChildCount();  
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {  
        View childView = getChildAt(i);  
        int measureHeight = childView.getMeasuredHeight();  
        int measuredWidth = childView.getMeasuredWidth();  
        childView.layout(mTotalWidth, mTotalHeight, mTotalWidth+measuredWidth, mTotalHeight + measureHeight);  
        mTotalWidth += measuredWidth;
        if (i%2 == 1) {
            mTotalWidth=0;
            mTotalHeight += measureHeight;  
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my touch listener:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                originalF = curr;
                break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    if ((curr.x-originalF.x)<screenWidth) {
        for (MapView mapView : allViews) {
          mapView.setX(100)
        mapView.requestLayout();
        mapView.forceLayout();
       }
        this.invalidate();
```

and I checked android documents, which said onlayout() should be called from layout when this view should assign a size and position to each of its children. Derived classes with children should override this method and call layout on each of their children.

I think my view Code do not has too much relation with that, but I will still paste them here.

```
private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     c = new Canvas(b);
     original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.placeholder);
     getScreenSize();
     final int canvasWidth = c.getWidth();
     final int canvasHeight = c.getHeight();
     Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "this new view's width is="+canvasWidth
             +"screen height is"+canvasHeight);     
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void getScreenSize() {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    try{
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;
        Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "screen width is="+screenWidth
                +"screen height is"+screenHeight);      
        }catch(NoSuchMethodError e){
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "not such method in getscreensize(", e);
        }
}

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         if (placeHolder != null) {
             canvas.drawBitmap(placeHolder, 0, 0, null);
        } 
    }

    //      stretch the image to the suitable size with parent MeasureSpec Param.
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    //     Log.d("this time", "parentSize is"+parentWidth+parentHeight);
           this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);        //because just set the parent size, so indeed no effect here.
    }

public void setMap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    //placeHolder = bitmap;
    placeHolder =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, parentWidth, parentHeight, true);
    invalidate();
}
```

In addition to that, I use

```
this.requestLayout();
this.forceLayout();
```

but they did not make sense.

May I address my main question again, how to call this onlayout() method?

Comment: i coding some thing like that and i used invalidate() instead

Comment: I also tried childrenView.invalidate() and this.invalidate(), they seem do not work for me ..

Comment: in my code i am using OnLayout  in initialize only and in touch event i making the update then call the invalide method

Comment: @mohammedmomn Actually I want the whole viewGroup(relativeView) dynamic move with my finger's moving, and I just find a way instead, is just use  this.setX(100), but I still want to know how to call onlayout() with touching here :)

Comment: could you post all custom view code , i will try it with my implementation

Comment: i will upload it tomorrow :)